# Creating a list of video links /// blocked by email obfuscation

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I'm fairly new to Python and coding in general so please bare with me. Overall, what im attempting is to create a script to open up my monthly fire department training, go to the monthly training video's, make a list of the potential videos in that data pod that change monthly and vary in how many video's we have for that month, and then play the video's. I've used Selenium to access the webpage and login. Im currently trying to make the list of possible monthly video's that'll ill be able to pull from and play. Show in the pic's are the "Assigments" and the code layout of the inspect video elements. Below is my code that I've come up with to pull the video links but everytime I run it it comes up with email obfuscation. Not sure what's causing this or how to get around it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Assignment block]

[image: Code snippet]

###Edit added all of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options #for maximize, disabling pop ups, enabling/disabling ext, etc..
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import httplib2
import re



#Target Solutions Credentials
username = "#"
password = "#"

#opening web page
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
#open window in maximize
driver.maximize_window()
#website
driver.get('https://www.targetsolutions.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#login screen button
lms_login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="riverbend-ButtonElement--oouR2NYdw9Ns5lb2VrED"]')
lms_login_button.click()


#username & password
username = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="username"]').send_keys("#")
password = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="password"]').send_keys("#")

#Login button
login_screen_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="form-login"]/ul/li[3]/input')
login_screen_button.click()

# Assignments page
my_assignments = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="navLeft"]/ul/li[2]/a')
my_assignments.click()

# EMAIL OBFUSCATION===============

def email(string):
    r = int(string[:2], 16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(string[i:i+2], 16) ^ r)
                     for i in range(2, len(string), 2)])
    return email

print(email('d0a3a5a0a0bfa2a490a4b1a2b7b5a4a3bfbca5a4b9bfbea3feb3bfbd'))

# WEBSCRAPER====================

url = 'https://app.targetsolutions.com/tsapp/dashboard/pl_fb/index.cfm?fuseaction=c_pro_assignments.showHome'

links = []
website = requests.get(url)
website_text = website.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text, features='html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Results: ====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 107.0.5304
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 107.0.5304 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\Wrd_3.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\107.0.5304.62\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55154/devtools/browser/d4e0b939-a7c4-4cfb-b828-1187823a031e
support@targetsolutions.com
/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#3a494f4a4a55484e7a4e5b485d5f4e4955564f4e5355544914595557

Which I understand to be some form of CloudFare Email Obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

I really can't tell what's going on with you because you didn't provided us with any more information in order to check and verify

Basically you are dealing with website which is behind CloudFlare protection
and the results you get is an email `support@targetsolutions.com`
you can try to decod the result with this script

```
def email(string):
    r = int(string[:2], 16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(string[i:i+2], 16) ^ r)
                     for i in range(2, len(string), 2)])
    return email


print(email('d0a3a5a0a0bfa2a490a4b1a2b7b5a4a3bfbca5a4b9bfbea3feb3bfbd')) // support@targetsolutions.com
```

it's Email Address Obfuscation you can read about it here [click here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-)

## **UPDATE**

after you post you'r full code
first this result you get

```
/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#3a494f4a4a55484e7a4e5b485d5f4e4955564f4e5355544914595557
```

is from the http request you cannot request to this site because it requires a login so you will not need the request section so let's delete it

```
#Target Solutions Credentials
username = "#"
password = "#"

#opening web page
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
#open window in maximize
driver.maximize_window()
#website
driver.get('https://www.targetsolutions.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#login screen button
lms_login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="riverbend-ButtonElement--oouR2NYdw9Ns5lb2VrED"]')
lms_login_button.click()


#username & password
username = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="username"]').send_keys("#")
password = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="password"]').send_keys("#")

#Login button
login_screen_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="form-login"]/ul/li[3]/input')
login_screen_button.click()

# Assignments page
my_assignments = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="navLeft"]/ul/li[2]/a')
my_assignments.click()
```

now you stop in your assignment page
[image]

now you will need to open your Devtools `F12` to open it then i need you to inspect your assignment and find the url tag and try to get a unique id or class just like how you get the assignments page button then all you need is to get all the elements with this unique value so your code should be like this

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options #for maximize, disabling pop ups, enabling/disabling ext, etc..
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



#Target Solutions Credentials
username = "#"
password = "#"

#opening web page
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
#open window in maximize
driver.maximize_window()
#website
driver.get('https://www.targetsolutions.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#login screen button
lms_login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="riverbend-ButtonElement--oouR2NYdw9Ns5lb2VrED"]')
lms_login_button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


#username & password
username = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="username"]').send_keys("#")
password = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="password"]').send_keys("#")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#Login button
login_screen_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="form-login"]/ul/li[3]/input')
login_screen_button.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Assignments page
my_assignmentspage = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value ='//*[@id="navLeft"]/ul/li[2]/a')
my_assignmentspage.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


my_assignmentslist = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = "find element with a unique value")
for my_assignment in my_assignmentslist:
    print(my_assignment.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer :) I was lazy to rewrite the JavaScript to Python. +1

Comment: I edited this to add all of my current code to help with the issue.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Forgive me, it's my first post on here. I added the new code to my script and updated the information on my question with the result below it. Still shows the "email protection" and is not producing a list of links.

Comment: @RyanD Looking at your code you've added to your question -> you don't call `email()` function on your links. Instead the last line `print(link)` try `print(email(link))`

Comment: @RyanD check the new update if you have any problem, don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

Using the module [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) you can re-utilize their Javascript decode routines:

```py
import js2py

js_script = """\
  function decode(email) {
      function r(e, t) {
        var r = e.substr(t, 2);
        return parseInt(r, 16);
      }

      function n(n, c) {
        for (var o = "", a = r(n, c), i = c + 2; i < n.length; i += 2) {
          var l = r(n, i) ^ a;
          o += String.fromCharCode(l);
        }
        return o;
      }

    var l = "/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#";
    return n(email, email.indexOf(l) + l.length);
  }
"""

decoder = js2py.eval_js(js_script)
email = decoder(
    "/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#d0a3a5a0a0bfa2a490a4b1a2b7b5a4a3bfbca5a4b9bfbea3feb3bfbd"
)
print(email)
```

Running the script prints your email.